# Почему код не выполняется в jsfiddle?

Tags: hotkeys, javascript

Почему полностью рабочий код:

```
document.onkeydown = function hotkeys(e) {
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    var k = e.keyCode;
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        if (k == 77) {
            alert('works');
        } // Ctrl + M
    }
}​
```

не выполняется в [в JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dimiork/YTTAk/), но при запуске из чистого документа *.html работает корректно.

Имею трабл: при внедрении данного кода на локальный рабочий сайт (я офисный планктон, да) — поведение аналогичное поведению на JSfiddle, в консоль ничего не падает, опыта в программировании практически нет, не представляю как такое даже погуглить.

[UPDATE] : Да, действительно, необходимо мышей навесить фокус на окно-отображения в jsFidle(правое нижнее). 
У меня же код не исполнялся (имеется самописное расширения для G.Chrome, которое наращивает некий функционал для сайта в локалке на работе) не знаю почему конкретно, но перемещение его самый верх файла расширения помогло.
Признателен ответившим, Ваши ответы натолкнули меня на решение :)

Comment: Opera 12.00, все работает. Попробуйте document.onkeydown = function(e) {

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо передать фокус `iframe`(кликнуть по нижнему правому окну) в котором выполняется JavaScript, после этого ваш код должен заработать.

Судя по всему с целью безопасности, в случае если `iframe` не имеет фокуса, то он просто не получает событий нажатия клавиш.